# Hibernate / JPA Mapped response - Subquery

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get all my data with a single custom build call. I am using Spring Boot version 2.3.8.
My problem is that i want to get a list of Strings with a subquery on the select statement in the repository.

Here is example of "TestMapper" with data which i would like to map.

```
private String location;
private Date checkoutRequestAt;
private Date checkoutAt;
private List<String> macAddressList;
private Boolean checkout;
```

The custom build query:

```
    @Query(value = "select " +
        "new test.jpa.TestMapper(" +
        "l.name," +
        "l.checkoutRequestAt," +
        "l.checkoutAt," +
        "(select d.macAddress from Device d where d.location = l)," +
        "l.checkout" +
        ") " +
        "from Location l " +
        "where l.name = :locationName")
TestMapper getCheckoutInformationUsingLocationName(@Param("locationName") String locationName);
```

Please note that the sub query should return more then 1 result. The List object is right!

When i bootup the Application i get following exception..
I am more then sure i do the select statement in wrong way. Maybe some one have example for this?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [test.jpa.TestMapper]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, java.util.Date, java.util.Date, java.lang.String, boolean [select new test.jpa.TestMapper(l.name,l.checkoutRequestAt,l.checkoutAt,(select d.macAddress from test.jpa.Device d where d.location = l),l.checkout) from test.jpa.Location l where l.name = :locationName]
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:725)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy171.createQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87)
```

By the way, if I change the List type to Object, I can start the spring boot project, but i will get exception that my select device query returns more then 1 result. The multiple results are expected as I can have multiple Devices assigned to a single location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible with plain JPA. Having said that, I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Location.class)
public interface TestMapper {
    @IdMapping("name")
    String getLocationName();
    Date getCheckoutRequestAt();
    Date getCheckoutAt();
    @Mapping("Device[locationId = VIEW(id)]")
    List<String> getMacAddressList();
    Boolean getCheckout();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`TestMapper a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, TestMapper.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<TestMapper> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!

Comment: Was end up with same solution, but your one more clear. 
Thank you for this advice, something new learned.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JPA has the capability of selecting a list of things in a subselect.

I therefore would switch to using a `JdbcTemplate` with a `ResultSetExtractor`.
The latter allows to build one result object from multiple rows of the result set.

With a SQL statement that replaces the subselect with a join, this should work just fine.

```sql
select 
    l.name,
    l.checkoutRequestAt,
    l.checkoutAt,
    d.macAddress,
    l.checkout" +
from Location l 
join Device d 
   on d.locationId = l.id
where l.name = :locationName
```

Something similar might be possible using JPA, but I don't see the benefit of going through JPA for this kind of things.